# Select box selects just one of multiple overlaping vertexes

Tags: selection-tools

If there is multiple vertexes with the same coordintates (i.e. on top of each other) in a mesh, the *select box* tool selects just one of them and ignores the rest.

- Is this a feature or a bug?
- Can it be switched/modified in order to really select all vertexes within the box even when they overlap

**background:**

I have some mesh exported from external editor where triangles (faces) are disconnected
=> each triangle has its own corner vertex => if you have e.g. 5 triangles meeting at one corner, you have 5 independent vertexes at that corner

In order to edit such a mesh I need to select all these vertexes and move them simultanously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Toggle X-Ray

In the 3D view header, check **Toggle X-Ray** (or press <kbd>Alt+Z</kbd>). You can now select the vertices sharing the same coordinates, but also the "backfacing" vertices (those hidden by the mesh).

### Merge vertices

If you really want to merge those vertices (so your 5 independent vertices become one unique vertex), you can use the Merge by Distance feature.

Select all your vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>), then go to Vertex/Merge vertices/By Distance (or press <kbd>Alt+M</kbd>). In the Last Operator menu, you can specify the distance under which the vertices will be merged.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I notice sometimes it works and sometimes not, but I did not realized it depends on "X-Ray" option